# How to add to an array - Arduino

Tags: arrays, arduino

I am trying to start off with a empty array and then generate a random number patten using the following code but I seem to not be able to get it to work.

```
 int sequence = {};

 random(1, 4);

 for (int i=0; i <= 7; i++){
 sequence[i] = random(1, 4);
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arduino is based on C++.

```
int sequence[8];

// You must initialize the pseudo-random number generator
// You can get a "random seed" using analogRead(0) if this
// pin isn't been used and unplugged.
randomSeed(analogRead(0));

for (int i=0; i <= 7; i++){
    sequence[i] = random(1, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it, it compiled just fine on my arduino IDE. I don't think it is necessary to seed the rand function, unless your application calls for a truly random number (not repeatable).

https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/random should help you out

```
void loop() {
 int sequence[8]; // this is an array

 for (int i=0; i <= 7; i++){
 // use modulo to get remainder, add 1 to make it a range of 1-4
 sequence[i] = rand() % 4 + 1;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not an array.
*This* is an array, `int sequence[7];`